I need additional GPU memory ubuntu 24.04
I have macmini 2012 late (quad core Intel Core i7-3615QM , RAM 16gb, Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) , SSD ) and i install ubuntu 24.04 LTS . All work perfect, even better then MacOs . But i have some problems with GPU, movies slow down . On MacOs my GPU have 1500 mb , but on ubuntu only 256 mb. How i can add GPU memory on ubuntu ?
$ inxi -G 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 23.2.6 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6
    compositor: gnome-shell v: 46.0 driver: dri: crocus gpu: i915
    resolution: 3440x1440~60Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: crocus,swrast
    platforms: wayland,x11,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.5 compat-v: 4.2 vendor: intel mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.2
    renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)
    
$ lspci -v -s 00:02.0 | grep Memory
   Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
   Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]


You don't. The Intel HD Graphics, your issue is more likely to be CPU-processing-bound not GPU RAM bound, as the Intel HD Graphics doesn't have dedicated GPU memory typically, and it's system-reserved by the hardware/BIOS/CPU in a specific amount. And usually hard-coded at a specific amount in the hardware itself, not adjustable by end users.
